# How to use the result of case 1 to another case

Tags: java

I have the program that input the amount of goods, and i have switch - case statement.

Case 1 : input the new goods data
Case 2 : print the report of all data

in case 1, the program is input the new data. The code is like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class inputData {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int add = 0;
        System.out.println("1. Create a new goods data\n2. Print the data");
        System.out.print("Type the option by typing sc: ");
        int menu = sc.nextInt();
        switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                String finalResult[][] = inputAgainConfirmation(createFirstRow(add), add);
                break;
            case 2: //the code is not written yet
                break;
        }
    }

    static String[] information() {
        String info[] = {"Code", "Name", "Purchase Price", "Selling Price", "Incoming Goods", "Outgoing Goods", "Damaged Goods", "Total Goods"};
        return info;
    }

    static String[][] createFirstRow(int add) {
        String info[] = information();
        String create[][] = new String[1][8];
        sc.nextLine();
        for (String[] create1 : create) {
            for (int j = 0; j < create[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("Input the " + info[j] + ": ");
                String input = sc.nextLine();
                create1[j] = input;
            }
        }
        return create;
    }

    static String[][] InputNewDataAgain(String[][] result, int add) {
        sc.nextLine();
        String info[] = information();
        String backup[][] = result;
        result = new String[result.length + 1][result[0].length];
        System.arraycopy(backup, 0, result, 0, backup.length);
        for (int i = backup.length; i < result.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("Input the " + info[j] + ": ");
                String input = sc.nextLine();
                result[i][j] = input;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    static String[][] inputAgainConfirmation(String[][] result, int add) {
        System.out.print("Create again? 1 = yes, 0 = no: ");
        int in = sc.nextInt();
        if (in == 1) {
            String createAgain[][] = InputNewDataAgain(result, ++add);
            return inputAgainConfirmation(createAgain, add);
        } else {
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

and i want to print the value of finalResult[][] in case 2.

How to save the finalResult[][] of case 1 statement so when i want to call the result, the program will not won't fill up anymore.

Comment: Almost exact repost of self-deleted question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59283282/how-to-use-the-result-of-case-statement-into-another-case-in-java

Comment: You start by learning about scope. In your example, that local variable `finalResult` **only** exists within that switch case block. It isn't visible anywhere else in your program. So step one: move the variable declaration **up**, so that the variable becomes visible in all the following code. But then of course: your case 2 code will have to check that the variable has been assigned a value. Alternatively, you could read about **fields** within classes, and use that, instead of local variables to hold results.

Answer (score 1):

In your code finalResult  is **local** variable  i.e scope of this variable is within that switch case block(case 1)  for printing this variable result in case 2 make that variable as **global** refer below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
                int add = 0;
                String finalResult[][] = new String[10][10];  // declare finalResult variable
                System.out.println("1. Create a new goods data\n2. Print the data");
                System.out.print("Type the option by typing sc: ");
                int menu = sc.nextInt();
                switch (menu) {
                    case 1:
                        finalResult[][] = inputAgainConfirmation(createFirstRow(add), add); // Assign value
                        break;
                    case 2: //the code is not written yet
                       // Print finalResult value    
                        break;
                }
            }
```